# wordpress add html and css code

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hello i would like to create a responsive table with div in wordpress article as this :

```
<div class="activite">
<div class="row nbr" > "0"</div>
        <div class="row" >Date</div>
        <div class="row" >Titre</div>
        <div class="row" >Descridivtion</div>
            <div class="rowForm">
                <div class="row" >cocher</div>
                <div class="row" >Nom</div>
                <div class="row" >S'inscrire</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <br>
    <div class="activite">
        <div class="row nbr" >&nbsdiv;1</div>
        <div class="row" >Date</div>
        <div class="row" >Titre</div>
        <div class="row" >Descridivtion</div>
            <div class="rowForm">
                <div class="row" >cocher</div>
                <div class="row" >Nom</div>
                <div class="row" >S'inscrire</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <br>
    <div class="activite">
        <div class="row nbr" >&nbsdiv;2</div>
        <div class="row" >Date</div>
        <div class="row" >Titre</div>
        <div class="row" >Descridivtion</div>
            <div class="rowForm">
                <div class="row" >cocher</div>
                <div class="row" >Nom</div>
                <div class="row" >S'inscrire</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <br>
```

(I would like to use div or p)

and i tested this style code.

```
    .nbr{
            width: 20px;
        }
        .row{
            border: 1px solid #000;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            padding: 5;
            }
        .rowForm{
            position: relative;
            float: left;            
        }
        br{
            position:relative;
            clear:left;
        }
        screen and (min-width: 360px){
        .rowForm{
            position: relative;
            float: none;            
         }          
        }
```

But my ask is how to implement this simple html code in  wordpress to show a normal table without plugin.

Comment: create and activate a child theme of your current theme, add an additional stylesheet to it, put this CSS in, and in the backend create a page where you insert your HTML code in "text view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding that code into the code tab on a Wordpress Post/Page should allow it to work, although it seems like a quite weird way to add a table. Simply copying over an actual table and pasting into Wordpress' visual editor displays it correctly and is quite responsive without even having to do much css.

Comment: Perfect ! i tested a style in an article it's not good because sometime there is a bug wordpress add br tags, but with a child theme it's okay, for a guy that read this ask don't use tab before each html  tag, thanks everybody !